# Codeigniter variable undefined error

Tags: codeigniter

I want to send some information to view from the controller

Following data i want to send into view

```
          $data['i_fname']=$f_fname;
          $data['i_lname']=$f_lname;
          $data['i_adline1']=$f_i_adline1;
          $data['i_adline2']=$f_i_adline2;
          $data['i_adline3']=$f_i_adline3;
          $data['i_phone']=$f_i_phone;
          $data['i_company']=$f_i_company;
          $data['i_state']=$f_i_state;
          $data['i_country']=$f_i_country;
          $data['i_email']=$f_i_email;


          $data['invoice_id']=$in_id_gen;
          $date['i_pname']=$f_product_domain_name;
```

but "$date['i_pname']=$f_product_domain_name;" this one not sending to my view other all data transfer work fine and i tried to assign a value for
$i_pname directly from the view and it working fine and i also tried to change name not working, but other working fine problem only for i_pname,

I get this error

A PHP ERROR WAS ENCOUNTERED

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: i_pname

Filename: views/invoice.php

Line Number: 104

is there any specific limit for transfer from controller to view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple, you spelt wrong. You have `$date` instead of `$data`

Change to

```
$data['i_pname'] = $f_product_domain_name;
```

From

```
$date['i_pname'] = $f_product_domain_name;
```